# IIS 10 server is not compressing .x3d file type

Tags: iis, compression, x3d, x3dom

I've couple of 3d models for my webpage which are high size. I'm using IIS server to host the site. IIS is compressing html, css and js files. But it is not compressing .x3d file. There is no 'content-encoding' in response header for .x3d file. What am i missing here? Do I need to add file ext/mime type somewhere in the server?? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mime type of.x3d should be model/x3d+xml, model/x3d+binary, model/x3d+vrml. So first of all, please set the correct mime type in IIS MiME TYPES.

Then you may need to add content type mode/* to IIS manager->site node->Configuration manager->system.webServer/httpCompression->static type->add->enable =true,mime type= model/*.

By default, IIS don't compress .x3d file.

[image]

Comment: It did work. x3d file is compressing. I got this link following your answer`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/dynamictypes/add#006` But even after compressing, I didn't see much reduction in loading time for the .x3d file. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Is there any abnormal in load time taken?If you need to improve performance issue, then please capture Failed request tracing log and check which process need to be improved.